# Issue with custom metric auc callback for keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, callback

I am trying to implement custom `roccallback` for keras. The call back function I wrote is below. I have to achieve a target of 0.90.

**AUROC callback:**

```
class rocback(Callback):
  def __init__(self, validation_data):
    super(rocback, self).__init__()
    # self.training_data = training_data
    self.validation_data = validation_data

  def on_train_begin(self, logs={}) :
    return

  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    probs = self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0])
    probs = np.round(probs)
    y_true = self.validation_data[1]
    y_true = np.round(y_true)
    score = roc_auc_score(y_true, probs, average='micro')
    logs['auc'] = score
```

Hence next callback which I wrote was to achieve the target.

```
class scoreTarget(Callback):
  def __init__(self, target):
    super(scoreTarget, self).__init__()
    self.target = target

  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    acc = logs['auc']
    if acc >= self.target:
      self.model.stop_training = True
```

The list of call back used is below:

```
roc_callback   = rocback((X_test_pooled_output, y_test))
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience=5)
tensorboard    = TensorBoard()
reduce_lr      = ReduceLROnPlateau(patience=3)
target         = scoreTarget(0.90)

callbacks = [
      roc_callback,
      early_stopping,
      tensorboard,
      reduce_lr,
      target,
]
```

The classifier function which I wrote is below:

```
class ReviewClassifier(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(ReviewClassifier, self).__init__()
    self.dense_1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')
    self.dense_2 = Dense(32, activation='relu')
    self.dense_3 = Dense(16, activation='relu')
    self.classify = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    self.dropout_1 = Dropout(0.2)
    self.dropout_2 = Dropout(0.2)
    self.dropout_3 = Dropout(0.2)

  def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.dense_1(inputs)
    x = self.dropout_1(x)
    x = self.dense_2(x)
    x = self.dropout_2(x)
    x = self.dense_3(x)
    x = self.dropout_3(x)
    x = self.classify(x)
    return x

review_classifier = ReviewClassifier()
review_classifier.build((None, 768))
review_classifier.summary()
```

The compile funtcion I wrote is this:

```
review_classifier.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                          optimizer='adam',metrics=[rocback])
```

fit function:

```
!rm -rf ./logs/*
history = review_classifier.fit(X_train_pooled_output, y_train,
                            batch_size=32, epochs=100,
                            callbacks=callbacks, 
                            validation_data=(X_test_pooled_output, y_test))
```

The error received is:

```
Epoch 1/100
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-fd7595a2c88c> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().system('rm -rf ./logs/*')
----> 2 history = review_classifier.fit(X_train_pooled_output, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=100,callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=(X_test_pooled_output, y_test))

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

TypeError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:758 train_step
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:408 update_state
        metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:90 decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:177 update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:618 update_state  **
        matches = ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)

    TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong in the custom callback which I created for roc?

Let me know what more inputs you need.

Comment: I know this is related to the ROC formula created, for some reason I am unable to call the function using metrics. Thats what's is leading me to this error.

Comment: Have you tried this [tf.keras.metrics.AUC](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC)

Comment: That didnt work either. Am I doing something wrong in creating the Neural Net or roc function. Can you please see if thats what is causing issues. Because I have used all the types of AUC function, nothing seems to be working for this model which I created.

Answer (score 2):

As we've mentioned in the comment, you can use built-in [tf.keras.metrics.AUC](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC) while compiling the model, easy-fast-efficient. But also no problem to use either [sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score). But using it in callback may slow down your training time. Try this:

```
class ROAUCMetrics(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, val_data):
        super().__init__()
        self.valid_x = val_data[0]
        self.valid_y = val_data[1]

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.val_aucs = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        pred = self.model.predict(self.valid_x)
        val_auc = roc_auc_score(self.valid_y, pred,  average='micro')
        print('\nval-roc-auc: %s' % (str(round(val_auc,4))),end=100*' '+'\n')
        self.val_aucs.append(val_auc)
        return
```

```
# sklearn auc 
roc = ROAUCMetrics(val_data=(x_val, y_val))

# tf.keras auc 
model.compile(.., ..., metrics=["AUC"])

# running 
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1024, 
          epochs=..., callbacks=[roc],
          validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

# get the values of auc, computed using sklearn auc
roc.val_aucs
```

However, note that both compute **AUC** differently, one uses Approximate AUC, another one uses Riemann sum, I've tested in one example and they pretty comparable but [sometimes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14834) didn't.

---

Based on your 1st comment, your set up should look like this:

```
# (1)
# compile with no metrics - as we have custom callback metric to use
review_classifier.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam')

# (2)
# or,
# we can add another metrics e.g 'accuracy' or whatever 
# here we use built-in AUC
review_classifier.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                          optimizer='adam',metrics=['AUC'])

# sklearn auc 
roc = ROAUCMetrics(val_data=(x_val, y_val))
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience=5)
tensorboard    = TensorBoard()
reduce_lr      = ReduceLROnPlateau(patience=3)
target         = scoreTarget(0.90)

callbacks = [
      roc,
      early_stopping,
      tensorboard,
      reduce_lr,
      target,
]

# fitting 
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1024, 
          epochs=..., callbacks=callbacks,
          validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Comment: Thank you for that code. What should I pass in this line ?

model.compile(.., ..., metrics=["AUC"])

Asking because I am still getting the same error.

Comment: As I mentioned above, pass the custom callbacks in the `.fit` - `model.fit(..  callbacks=[roc]`. That's it. Additionally, I showed that you can also pass built-in metrics - `['AUC']`

Comment: It should work. If you still face an error, then use `metrics=["AUC"]` but don't use callback this time, if it works, let make know but if it not, there is something probably wrong in your setup.

Comment: I tried that it didnt work. I keep on getting the same error.

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible code? Because that works just fine in my case.

Comment: I used this : tf.keras.metrics.AUC. Not sure what is wrong with the code.Thanks for helping out.

Comment: That's the same thing I recommended you to do, built-in `metrics=["AUC"]`.

Comment: But if you possibly can provide some reproducible code with some dummy data, I can help you to debug with this code.